# JS conteúdo por tempo

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer um código JS para exibir determinado conteúdo relacionado com os dias, conforme no exemplo abaixo.

dia 1 = html a
dia 2 = html b
dia 3 = html c

Tipo, quando for no dia 1, vai aparecer um conteúdo do html a e quando finalizar as 24 horas vai para o dia 2 e exibe o html b e assim por diante.

Quero apenas saber a base de como executar isso, alguém consegue me dar um help?

Comment: Quantos dias diferentes há? um por semana, um por mês, ou um numero fixo que vai rodando?

Comment: E outra pergunta, se a página recarregar o utilizador vê o mesmo conteúdo desse dia ou pode ser outro conteúdo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somente com JS nao e um jeito bom de fazer isso, o ideal seria um backend que traz renderiza somente o conteudo do dia.

Mas pra voce entender uma maneira simplista poderia ser assim

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date = new Date()
  var today = date.getDate()
  //isso e so preguica de copiar e colar 30 divs, mas da pra entender a ideia geral
  lazyLoad()
  
  //mesmo nome de classe ali de baixo na linha 15
  var $todayContent = $('.content-day-'+today)
  $todayContent.show()
})

function lazyLoad(){
    var $main = $('#main')
    for(var i=0; i<31; i++){
      var day = i+1
      $main.append('<div class="content content-day-'+day+'">'+
        '<h2>Sou o Conteudo do dia '+day+'</h2>'+
      '</div>')
    }
  }
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Ai voce precisa ajeitar pra suas necessidades, tipo um `setInerval` pra mudar automaticamente para o dia as 00:00h e por ai vai, depende das suas necessidades.

Comment: Valeu mano, era isso mesmo, abs.